# Iterating over multiple rows in Python - Science Data Cleaning

Tags: python, csv

I am working with a large private dataset and I need some assistance in figuring out how to iterate a program over multiple rows.

```
import csv

with open('report_export.csv') as f:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    report_export = list(reader)

x = report_export[25]["Text_Content"]
x.split(sep='. ')[1]

 ' Azithromycin is an antibiotic agent and a member of a subclass of 
   macrolide antibiotics with bactericidal and bacteriostatic activities.
```

report_export.csv is a data file pull from a local database containing information chemicals from publications. I want some textual information from this file. It is located under the column "Text Content". "25" is a random row that worked as proof of principle for the code. The x.split(sep='. ')[1] is used 
 for isolating the desired string and differentiating between decimals and periods. This file is rather large, 5000 rows on CSV, and I want to be able to extract statements about the chemicals similar to output above.

I am having difficulty figuring out how to iterate over multiple rows in this case. I need the program to read over the rows, retrieve the 2nd string (1 position) from the list, and be able to save this data to a new csv file.

Any assistance with achieving the ability to iterate over rows would be helpful.

Thank you!

Best,

PEB

Comment: Can you please give us an example of how your file looks like? Also.. have a look at **Pandas** library and specifically the pandas.read_excel() function.

Comment: Deleted data science tag.

Answer (score 2):

Look into pandas `pandas.read_csv(filename)` method

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

And in order to iterate over the rows use the method iterrows()

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `list(reader)` will read the entire file into a list. To iterate over rows in the csv file without reading everything in at once, replace that line with a loop:

```
for row in reader:
    x = row["Text_Content"]
    etc.
```

That said, five thousand rows is not that much, so you could also just iterate over the list `report_export` that you created:

```
for row in report_export:
    x = row["Text_Content"]
    etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. If all you want to do is extract and write to a file, just use a some sort of `writer` object from `csv`, and use the reader-writer combination, while you iterate *directly over the reader object*:

```
import csv
with open('report_export.csv', newline='') as infile,\ 
            open('report_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:

    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    fieldnames = ["Text_content"]
    writer = csv.DicWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for row in reader: # iterates over the csv row-by-row
        data = row["Text_Content"].split(sep='. ')[1]
        writer.writerow({"Text_content": data})
```

The above assumes Python 3.